# Suppose $R$ is a ring and $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$ such that $(ab)^n=ab, \forall a,b \in R.$ Then $ab = 0 $ iff $ba=0 \ ?$

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is a ring and there exists $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$ such that $(ab)^n=ab, \forall a,b \in R.$ Could anyone advise me on how to prove/disprove that $ab = 0$ iff $ba=0, \forall a,b \in R \ ?$

Hints will suffice, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $ab=0$. Then $ba=(ba)^2=b(ab)a=0$. Conversely, if $ba=0$, then $ab=(ab)^2=a(ba)b=0$.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the hint.

Comment: why is $ba=(ba)^2.$ ?

Comment: He is just giving an example

Comment: If $ab=0,$ then $ba = (ba)^n = b(ab)a...ba = 0$

Comment: what happens if n = 1? does the proof still work?

Comment: @user2675516 No, there exist rings where $ab = 0$ and $ba \neq 0$. The matrices give one example.

Comment: @Asvin i can't seem to find such a matrix

Comment: @user2675516 Both 2x2 matrices: $[1;0;0;0] , [0;0;1;0]$. Sorry for the non-formatting, hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

A thermonuclear way to do his is to notice that the hypothesis implies that for all $a\in R$ there is an $n>1$ such that $a^n=a$ and to remember that this implies, according to a famous theorem of Jacobson, that $R$ is commutative.

Comment: I am assuming that the ring has a unit, of course.