# Let $R$ be a ring. Is it true that if $(ab)^n = ab$ for all $a,b \in R$, then $R$ is commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring. Is it true that if $(ab)^n = ab$ for some $n >0 $, for all $a,b \in R$, then $R$ is commutative?

[Suppose $R$ is a ring and $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$ such that $(ab)^n=ab, \forall a,b \in R.$ Then $ab = 0 $ iff $ba=0 \ ?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777344/suppose-r-is-a-ring-and-exists-n-in-mathbbz-0-such-that-abn-ab/777368#comment2478717_777368)

According to the post above, the Mariono claims that it is true. Is it true? How can I prove it? Especially when n = 1.

Comment: For $n=1$ it's trivially false. $(ab)^1=ab$ always and you just need any noncommutative ring as a counterexample. For $n>1$, I suspect there may be a counterexample but I'm not sure.

Comment: Does that mean that the solution in the post is wrong?

Comment: Just looked at the post. One answer wasn't a solution. The other one assumes $n>1$ and identity and that one is correct.

Comment: @avid19 yup my concern is why can we assume n>1. It seems to fail when n = 1.

Comment: As I had said, it does fail when n=1. But if n>1, it holds.

Comment: "$n>0$" was clearly just a trivial typo that anyone could make (I went ahead and corrected it there). If you sought out Jacobson's theorem, this would be apparent.

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that the question in the title asks about commutativity, but the result mentioned in the body of the post does NOT tell you the ring is commutative.